# Calculating the area under a P-V curve in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, area, curve

I collected data in `LabVIEW` to generate a `P-V (pressure-volume) curve` (see link below). I now need to find the area under the curve.

The catch is that there are two portions of the curve I need to address: the area with a red (-) needs to be subtracted from the one with green (+)s. The spacing on the x-axis is inconsistent as well.

I've seen some suggestions for using `trapz` and `polyarea`, but none of those worked for me. I tried manually finding the bounds, but limiting my trapz/polyarea calls to those bounds still resulted in an area that was entirely too small. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code attempts using `trapz` and `polyare`. Also when you say area under the curve... I assume you actually mean area within the closed regions?

Comment: Also can you show us your X and Y values? Do you have around four Y values for each X? What exactly do you mean by "The spacing on the x-axis is inconsistent"?

Comment: Is everything a single graph? is the curve self intersecting?

Comment: I apologize--notification emails were routed to my spam folder, so I didn't see any of these questions.

I've since figured it out (a different way), but thank you all the same!

Comment: Heey user3326627, i have the same question, but i cannot figure out how to do it. As it seems you have found a solution, could you post it here? I would really appreciate it.